# css правильная верстка фоновых изображений

Tags: css, css3

Нужно сверстать вот такой [image: введите сюда описание изображения] блок (шапку) адаптивно. Как такую вещь правильно делать, делать каждую картинку отдельным блоком и делать наложения фона (реально ?), или сделать одним блоком в котором будет фон как одна целая картинка. По центру еще будет текст.Делаю на bootstrap.

Comment: В зависимости от того будут ли меняться флаги, форма и цвет прозрачного слоя. Если один раз и навсегда - делайте картинку, если возможны изменения делайте множественный бэкграунд - две картинки с разным `background-position`, а наложение полупрозрачным круговым градиентом.

Comment: нечего не будет менятся (все статика), только вот думаю на счет адаптивности

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```css
.block {
  background-color: #377D53;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle, #377D53 50%,
                            rgba(55, 125, 83, 0.8) 70%,
                            rgba(55, 125, 83, 0.5) 100%),
    url(http://www.qqxxzx.com/images/usa-flag-wallpaper/usa-flag-wallpaper-10.jpg),
    url(http://www.techweekeurope.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Britain1.jpg);
  background-position: center center, top left, top right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

[Или посмотреть код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/u6tx8q49/)

Так можно использовать `jpg`-изображения без прозрачности, накладывая сверху цветовой градиент. Обратите внимание, множественные `background-image` рисуются в порядке "Первый в стилях - На верхнем слое", поэтому градиент у нас идет на первом месте.

И за счет `background-position` - выравниваете все три изображения, включая градиент.

`background-size: contain` растянет изображения флагов так, чтобы они заняли все доступное пространство по меньшей величине, нам это подойдет лучше, чем растягивание по большей величине в случае с `background-size: cover`.

Answer (score 2):

Для адаптации фонового изображения лучше использовать:

```
.block {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
 }
```

> cover -  масштабирует изображение с сохранением пропорций так, чтобы его
>   ширина или высота равнялась ширине или высоте блока.

```
 .block {
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
          background-size: contain;
 }
```

> contain масштабирует изображение с сохранением пропорций таким
>   образом, чтобы картинка целиком поместилась внутрь блока.

Для двух фоновых изображений:

```
.block {
    background-color: color;
    background-image: url(img_flwr.gif), url(paper.gif);
    background-position: right bottom, left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
              background-size: cover;
}
```